# Finding the most commonly associated items for every item within a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, market-basket-analysis

I'm really struggling to find an answer to this - I'm trying to find the most commonly sold together items for each item in a list. I've managed to get my data looking something like this:

```
order_number    item_name
0   517640  [nan]
1   517660  [a]
2   517663  [a, b]
3   517665  [a, c, d, e]
4   517666  [c, a, b, d]
```

The code I'm currently using is:

```
import itertools
list(itertools.combinations(items.item_name[0], 3))
combinations_list = []

for row in items.item_name:
    combinations = list(itertools.combinations(row, 2))
    combinations_list.append(combinations)
combinations_list[:2]

combination_counts = pd.Series(combinations_list).explode().reset_index(drop=True)

combination_counts.value_counts()[:50]
```

This returns the 50 most common pairs that appear in this list (I think ).

Any ideas how I can get the list to show the 3 most commonly sold items alongside every item we currently sell?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: It looks like what you are trying to do is frequent itemset mining / association rule learning. There are libraries for that.

Comment: Thanks - do you have a recommendation for a library I can use? I'm very new to Python, so any guidance would be much appreciated 

Answer (score 0):

For every item, you need to keep the list of counts of the other items appearing in the same order. Scan the list of orders and increment the counters for every pair. In the end, just report the three items with the largest count in each list.

For implementation, if the lists are sparse (a given item appears with few other ones), use a dictionary per item. Otherwise, used an array of counts.

Comment: Sorry, I'm actually very new to Python - working through the basics still. I found the above on another stackoverflow page. Would you mind pointing me in the right direction in figuring out how to do this? Thanks 